# Jasmine calls.length and callCount are undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine, bdd, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to test my chrome extension with [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) but I'm having trouble getting `calls.length` and `callCount` to behave as expected. Both cases return `undefined`.

I've included a sample of the code and the spec. Here's the rest of the code if it helps: https://github.com/DruRly/kamikaze/tree/closeIdleTab

**How to reproduce:**

- `git clone https://github.com/DruRly/kamikaze/tree/closeIdleTab`
- `cd kamikaze`
- `open SpecRunner.html`

spec/kamikazeSpec.js

```
describe("kamikaze", function() {
  describe("closeIdleTabs", function(){
    it("calls closeIdleTab for each tab received", function(){
      spyOn(kamikaze, 'closeIdleTab');

      kamikaze.closeIdleTabs([1,2,3]);
      expect(kamikaze.closeIdleTab.calls.length).toBe(3);
    })
  })
})
```

src/kamikaze.js

```
kamikaze = {
  ...

  closeIdleTabs: function(tabs){
    tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      test.closeIdleTab(tab);
    })
  },

  closeIdleTab: function(tab){
    if(tabTimeStamps[tab.id]){
      var secondsSinceUpdated = getSecondsSinceUpdated(tab.id)
      if(secondsSinceUpdated > (minutesUntilIdle * 60)){
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id)
      }
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

Comment: +10 for the quality and format of the question. Most people would have stopped after the first 2 lines (literally) ! (Relevant code, link to full code and steps to reproduce the issue - I hate the fact it was so easy to answer this one :))

Comment: Thanks @ExpertSystem! Felt like I was going crazy. I still may be but I was also looking at outdated docs :)

Comment: It would be nice if the repo was still available for reference.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The Jasmine APIs have changed a bit in the 2.x version "series".
According to the **[latest docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-23)** you should use the `count()` method:

```
expect(kamikaze.closeIdleTab.calls.count()).toBe(3);
```

<sub>I also tried that with your code and all tests pass successfully.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

Alternative syntax (with a bit nicer output on failure) would be

```
expect(kamikaze.closeIdleTab).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```

[Here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledTimes) is some documentation.